# How to easily find a coroutine that has timed out?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

key problem ：`asyncio.wait(aws,timeout=1,return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)` Is there a simple way to check if the returned task has timed out?

This is an extended question.

The scene is like this:

- Total number of coroutines is unknown
- server only allows 10 links
- The server will return a seemingly correct result (eg returning an incorrect page)
- The server sometimes does not return any data.
- Maximum possible access to all data

So in order to get data faster, I need to limit the number of coroutines. Check the returned page. And timeout.

There are two simple methods at present.
1. similar to the thread, use queue to build a coroutine pool + 10 infinite loop coro. I don't really like it. In fact, this method works very fast.
2. I tried to use the high-level API of async python3.7, try to simplify the structure of the program, using `while tasks` & `asyncio.wait` & `return_when`.

Here I came across a problem with how to find timeouts for coroutines.

I built a simple demo:

```py
import asyncio


async def test(delaytime):
    print(f"begin {delaytime}")
    await asyncio.sleep(delaytime )
    print(f"finish {delaytime} ")

async def main():
    # the number of tasks is unknow,range(10) is just a demo
    allts = list(range(10))
    ts = []
    while len(ts)<5:
        arg = allts.pop()
        t = asyncio.create_task(test(arg))
        t.arg = arg
        ts.append(t)
    while ts:
        dones,pendings = await asyncio.wait(ts,timeout=2,return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        for t in dones:
            # if check t.result() is error , i can append ts again
            print(t.arg,"is done")
            ts.remove(t)
            while len(ts)<5:
                if len(allts):
                    arg = allts.pop()
                    t = asyncio.create_task(test(arg))
                    t.arg = arg
                    ts.append(t)
                else:
                    break
        # for t in pendings:
        #   # if can check t is timeout , i can append ts again
        #   pass

if __name__=="__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

After debugging, I know that `return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED`, the tasks returned by `asyncio.wait` are in the pendings, except for the completed tasks.
However, I can't tell which task is timeout. 
I thought about using `wait_for`, but `wait_for` has no `return_when` argument.

Is there a simple way to determine the timeout task in order to re-join `ts`?

Comment: Since it's async, the logic is to either emit a signal or to leave a trace. The simplest way is probably to write to a log file, as you should always be doing.

Comment: Try checking `t.exception()`. Also, it's "pending", not "pedding".

Comment: @user4815162342 `t.exception()` is invalid, all the tasks in pendings show `Exception is not set.`, which is actually an `asyncio.InvalidStateError`. Can't tell if the task in pendings has timed out.
Sorry, my spelling is wrong.

Comment: Does the approach from the answer work for your case?

Comment: @user4815162342 Your answer is very useful, thx! Although I still think this usage is ugly. But just using asyncio's High-level APIs, this is probably the best way to write.    In addition to the `queue` and `wait(FIRST_COMPLETED)` mentioned above, is there any other pythonic idea for this scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the approach of using `wait(return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)` is fundamentally incompatible with the use of `timeout`. Since different tasks have started at different times, a single `timeout` argument obviously can't apply to all tasks. If you want to use `return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED`, wrap each task in [`asyncio.wait_for`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for):

```
t = asyncio.create_task(asyncio.wait_for(test(arg), 2))
```

Then, when the task is done, you can use `t.exception()` to test if it has timed out, in which case it will return `asyncio.TimeoutError`. This check should only be performed among the *done* tasks.

Comment: I saw the source code of `asyncio.wait`, which uses only `waiter` instead of appending a `waiter` to each `task` to determine the timeout. When `FIRST_COMPLETED`, the waiter is cleared. Therefore, it is impossible to identify the timeout of each task in the backend.
I misunderstood the use of `wait_for`, and thought it was a `wait` like.
I tried `as_completed`, but he didn't return a task, and couldn't attach parameters for retry, not meeting the scene requirements.

Comment: Your answer completely solved the problem of `wait(FIRST_COMPLETED)`, thx!
Personally feel that the `task` object lacks the initial parameter properties (so that you have to attach dynamic properties to the task object for retry), and the timeout property of `wait(FIRST_COMPLETED)` is awkward. Is it just that I think so?

Comment: @notback I think there is no real problem, and `wait(return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)` is simply not the right tool for the job. Personally I would go with the solution of a queue and a fixed number of workers, with `asyncio.wait_for` inside the worker to enforce timeout.

Comment: @ user4815162342  `queue` solution, for timeout, connection limit, more convenient. But for returning seemingly correct results, as well as various retry operations, the number of lines of code is much larger. So I tried the solution of `wait(FIRST_COMPLETED)`. By the way, what is the better situation for `wait(FIRST_COMPLETED)`?